# Does a perfect group always have trivial center?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G^{'}$ is Commutator subgroup of $G$  and $G=G{'} $.  Can I show that $Z(G)= \{e \} $?

I think it's not True but I can not find example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ has nontrivial center and equals its derived group.

Comment: Or for a finite example, the same works with $\mathbb{R}$ replaced by $\mathbb{F}_5$.

Comment: dang you beat me to it. Although if you've got the time it might be worth it to recall what $SL_2$ is equal to its commutator.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: Yes, totally. I liked the Lie aspect , but the algebra should work the same-- I guess using elementary matrices, for not too small fields. This got me to read a bit  about perfect groups ( good call with the editing!)

Comment: @Ben Smith: Yep, here goes my Lie side. Btw, I have to redo the generation of $SL_2$ in terms of elementary matrices, that should help I suppose.

Comment: @orangeskid is there any way to collaborate on answers? I know I have this proof typed up already from an assignment in a course on linear algebraic groups.

Comment: @BenSmith: Maybe you can add another answer, that could be very useful